# unable to get values outside the db Query execution callback

Tags: node.js, angular

IM new to nodejs, help me understand

> unable to get values in categories array as if i print values outside forloop
>
> if i print inside second query its printing the changes

```
var sql = 'select * from categories where adp_customers_id = ?  and parent_id = 0 and display_on_screen = 1  and category_type= \'COLLECTION\' ';
mysqlConnection.query(sql,[ adpCustomer ],  function (err,  result) {
if (err) throw err;
var categories = [];  // i think values should be reflected here nut no luck, what im missing  
if(result.length > 0){
for(var a =0; a<result.length ; a++){
var subcategories = [];
var currentCategory = 0;
currentCategory = result[a].id;
var name = result[a].name;
var description = result[a].description;
var sql = 'select * from categories where adp_customers_id = ?  and parent_id = ? and display_on_screen = 1  and category_type= \'COLLECTION\'';
    mysqlConnection.query(sql, [adpCustomer, currentCategory],  function (err, subCategoryResult) {
if (err) throw err;
if (subCategoryResult.length > 0) {
for (var a = 0; a < subCategoryResult.length; a++) {
subcategories.push({
"id": subCategoryResult[a].id,
"name": subCategoryResult[a].name,
"description": subCategoryResult[a].description,
});
}
}
categories.push({
"id": currentCategory,
"name": name,
"description": description,
"children": subcategories
});
console.log("categores = "+  JSON.stringify(categories));   // working here
});
}
console.log("categores = "+  JSON.stringify(categories));   // not working here WHY
return res.json(categories);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you populate the array in a callback function of your query. The "working" line is within the callback, and the console log happens right after you handled the data. The other is outside, executed before the callback is finished.

You should look into Promises (or callbacks), this will never work this way.

Comment: Rabel : can you suggest me better example

Comment: Your function should return a promise instead, and resolve it in your callback. You can not wait for the result, one solution is to pass a function and call it with the result - as the query does - or use a promise. Do some research about them, I suggest the Promise way, as it is the better approach.